# Loading layer and check for polygon WkbType in QGIS 3.0

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I am trying to edit a plugin to work in QGIS 3.0 and want to check for layer is polygon.

```
for layer in layers:  
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.wkbType() == Qgis.Polygon:  
        self.dlg.comboBox.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
```

Its throwing error

> "if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.wkbType() == Qgis.Polygon :
>   AttributeError: type object 'Qgis' has no attribute 'Polygon'"

How can I use WKBType in QGIS 3.0?

Comment: I suggest you to use `layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry`, which is a short way to handle all possible polygon geometries (e.g., Polygon, PolygonZ, PolygonM, PolygonZM, MultiPolygon, MultiPolygonZ, and so on).

Comment: @GermánCarrillo - I think you should post your comment as an **answer** :)

Comment: I think that would depend on what @sachin-kumar actually needs, but Ok, I'll do it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/doc/api_break.dox#L427-L428), the enum `QGis.WkbType` becomes `QgsWkbTypes.Type` in QGIS v3.

So, a valid statement would be:

```
layer.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.Polygon
```

However, that would not be useful if you have, for instance, multi polygons.

Therefore, I suggest you to use:

```
layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry
```

which is a short way to handle all possible polygon geometries (e.g., Polygon, PolygonZ, PolygonM, PolygonZM, MultiPolygon, MultiPolygonZ, and so on).

Comment: The two enum lists and their return values can be found at https://qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html